# SQL - Grouping sets with multiple conditions

Tags: sql

I have a large (15 million record) database from which we produce a number of different tables, we're trying to refactor our code to produce all of the information in one underlying data set. This has led me to use multiple UNIONS which usually have one different filter, or group by one extra variable. This has led to the code being quite long (I think the total will be 8 or so UNIONS).

I have been reading about grouping sets and this, on the face of it, looks like the ideal solution to the problem. The issue I have is with the HAVING clause. A lot of my UNIONS filter differently on the same variables; so I'm not sure if its possible to set up the HAVING clause to include one subset of variables in one grouping set and another subset in the next group.

A very simple example. People entering a music contest, you can enter multiple times with each instrument and can enter with multiple instruments. Our raw data is one row per person per entry. We want to take the best score for each instrument:

```
Select Person_ID, Solo_group, instrument_type, Instrument
, Max (Score) as [Score]
into #Scores
from #Entries
where Solo_group = 1
where instrument in (Flute, guitar, oboe, drums, tuba, violin)
Group by Person_ID, Solo_group, instrument_type, Instrument
UNION
Select Person_ID, Solo_group, instrument_type
, 'Specialist' as [Instrument]
, Max (Score) as [Score]
into #Scores
from #Entries
where Solo_group = 1
where instrument in (Flute, guitar, oboe, drums, tuba, violin)
Group by Person_ID, Solo_group, instrument_type
UNION
Select Person_ID, Solo_group, instrument_type, [Instrument]
, Max (Score) as [Score]
into #Scores
from #Entries
where Solo_group = 0
Group by Person_ID, Solo_group, instrument_type, [Instrument]
```

The code may have errors, I just made it up on the fly. But the issue is:
- Batch one gives each person their max score, per instrument, in the 'specialist' instruments
- Batch two does the same thing, but for all the specialist instruments combined
- Batch three includes all instruments, but includes solo and group performances.

So for grouping sets, I'm pretty sure I can just use:

```
Grouping sets (
      (Person_ID, Solo_group, instrument_type, Instrument),
      (Person_ID, Solo_group, instrument_type)
              )
```

But the first grouping set needs to apply the solo_group filter differently (and in my actual code, there is more that needs to be differentiated). Is it possible to use HAVING to apply the solo_group variable differently to the same grouping set? Also worth noting, that the [instrument] filter in the where clause will also need to be differentiated.

I've just had a thought, I presume I actually need three grouping sets:

```
    Grouping sets (
      (Person_ID, Solo_group, instrument_type, Instrument),
      (Person_ID, Solo_group, instrument_type, Instrument),
      (Person_ID, Solo_group, instrument_type)
              )
```

But for the second set to have an additional variable that differentiates it from the first (e.g. a dummy variable to identify it as the solo_group = 0 set). Then have three HAVING clauses? One for each set?

If this is possible, what would the HAVING causes look like? I'm having real trouble working out how they actually work.

Comment: What DB are you using? I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do, but the HAVING clause is just like a WHERE clause, only operating on values after you've grouped them. For example, if I've got a table of users, and I only want to select names that appear more than once, I could write `select u.name from users u group by u.name having count(*) > 1`. I can't put an aggregate function like COUNT in the WHERE clause, because WHERE only operates on the rows before they're aggregated, but I can put it in the HAVING clause.

Comment: Microsoft SQL (MSSQL)?. Yep, so I'm trying to apply different HAVING clauses to the different grouping sets. When I use UNION, I can apply different WHERE clauses to each set of data; but I can't work out how I move those different WHERE clauses into the HAVING clause when using grouping sets and apply them to the specific grouping set I want. I'm guessing it is not possible?